# What algorithms are used to find a minimum spanning forest?

Tags: algorithm, graph, minimum-spanning-tree, minimum-spanning-forest

As Wikipedia says:

> Minimum spanning forest is a union of the minimum spanning trees for
>   its connected components.

For finding minimum spanning tree we can use for example [Prim's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm), [Kruskal's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm), or [Borůvka's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bor%C5%AFvka%27s_algorithm).

What algorithm can we use to find minimum spanning forest?

Comment: Same algorithms applied to each connected component separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how you need any other algorithm than you use for trees - you may need to adapt them a bit.
If you use for example Kruskal's algorithm you get all cheapest edges in every sub graph/minimum spanning tree of your (now also minimum spanning) forest. Or you can use Prim's algorithm and if your iteration stops, restart it with a node that is not connected yet (i.e. with another tree).

So my answer in one sentence: "The algorithms used to find a minimum spanning forest are the same ones that are used to find a minimum spanning tree - in some cases with adaptions and in some cases without them."